# Docker-- You need to specity one of the followings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

You need to specify one of the following:
mysql_container   |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
mysql_container   |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
mysql_container   |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

my compose.yml file is here
version: "3"

```
  services:
    db:
      platform: linux/x86_64
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: mysql_container
      ports:
        - "7000:3306"
      volumes:
        - /Users/pn_jh/Desktop/DockerProjects/jango-mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql/data
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:rootmysql
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql

    web:
      build: .
      container_name: django-container
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

can you give me a answer?
I need it!

Comment: Check the offical docu. There is an Example Compose file with MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD set:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:rootmysql -> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootmysql

Answer (score 0):

when setting the environment variables in your docker-compose file don't mix `:` with `=`, choose one of them
for example

```
environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:rootmysql
        - MYSQL_USER:user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD:mysql
        - MYSQL_DATABASE:MySQL
```

or

```
environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootmysql
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysql
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql
```